# How to deserialize inherited POJO from JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize POJO Object (`NoteObj`) from JSON. The POJO object extends `Item` (abstract Object) on which I have a Custom Deserializer. This Custom Deserializer ensures that if an `IItem` Class is required as POJO, the particular Class (either Edge or Vertex) is returned instead of abstract Class.

However when I want to return `NoteObj` instance when I call to use it.
But if I call the deserializer with `NoteObj.class`, I always get `ArrayList<Vertex>` instead, because the `NoteObj extends Item` and my custom `ItemDeserializer` is used instead of some default Jackson Deserializer.

IItem Interface Class:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(
  using = ItemDeserializer.class
)
public interface IItem {
...
}
```

The Abstract Class Item

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonDeserialize(
  using = ItemDeserializer.class
)
public abstract class Item implements IItem, Serializable {
...
}
```

The POJO object where I need not to use the ItemDeserializer, but a standard Jackson Deserializer, so that I get the NoteObj

```java
public class NoteObj extends Item implements IItem {
...
}
```

The other Class which is returned by ItemDeserialzier (Edge is the same):

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDeserializer.None.class)
public class Vertex extends Item implements IVertex, Serializable {
...
}
```

The code of ItemDeserializer is:

```java
public class ItemDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<IItem> {
 protected ItemDeserializer() {
 }

 public IItem deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
  TreeNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();

   if (node.get("_from") != null) {
     return (Edge)jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node, Edge.class);
   } else { 
     return (Vertex)jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(node, Vertex.class);
   }
 }
}
```

I have already tried to use @JsoNDeserialize with JsonNodeDeserializer.class in the NoteObj Class definition, but this doesn't return POJO, but LinkedHashList. I tried to use None.class but this still goes to ItemDeserializer.

I had an idea that I would modify the ItemDeserializer to return the requested POJO (e.g. not only Edge, Vertex, but a Generic class, e.g. NoteObj). However I don't know how to determine what Generic Class was requested to be returned.

Comment: Have you tried `@JsonDeserialize(using = StdDeserializer.class)`? Or `BeanDeserializer.class`?

Comment: Yes I tried both, each of them throws the Exception:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor`
This is also the reason, why my ItemDeserializer has the empty Constructor, because it was failing on the same exception.